# Template for product-category page

Tags: categories, templates, page-template, woocommerce-offtopic

Where can I find the template that is used for the product-category page?
The general template is "page-full.php".
But where is the template for the single-product page (single.php?) and the product-category page? I'd like to edit them to show elements that are not visible on other pages and vice versa.
Much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the WooCommerce documentation about their template structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme doesn't necessarily include all these template files.

It might just use `index.php` to serve the single page template as well as listings (category, date, author, tag, etc).

The articles [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) from the codex should get you on the right road with theme development.

If you add a `single.php` file, WP will use that instead of `index.php` for example.

'product-category.php' (as @ialocin rightly says) is almost certainly a WooCommerce template file and the way you override that is different. They have good docs: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

The general principle is the same - you override the default template (index.php) with successively more-specific templates.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. So I essentially have to copy the existing page template and edit it. So I have to rename it "product-category.php"?
Or rather. Where do I add the link for the additional template file?

Comment: Like I said in my comment under your question, take a look at the WC documentation about their template structure and how to override templates. Because it differs a bit from the WP standard. @theHubi

Comment: I've skimmed through the text and get the basic concept. There's always a main file and a "substitute" file, if the first one does not exist. So essentially adding a "product-category.php" adds it automatically to that system?

Comment: OP - answer edited above, @ialocin totally right of course.